# Padding mode not valid when try do decrypt a JWE payload with RSA-OAEP-256 and A256GCM

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, cryptography, rsa, oaep

I have no expertise with cryptography, i'm trying to decrypt a JWE payload in ASP.net core C#, the information that i have is the encryption was performed with **RSA-OAEP-256** and **A256GCM**, so i'm using Jose libraries do deal with cryptography, the code is like:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUC0yNTYiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.rb3as5DV3PjfYM9cmxO1uE_OaLBt_gFMG9oe1iW_8999KNXEcxAuENaAJgD0fIWdrYD0UwDfkPxzG2cKy3SkvhQE5af7HNDuJBK7p_jjWZMNxtLO3IWCVbcYmH8r-TJEf4MPrDQi_0wP0QLIqH9aR3EVzRdkZ0tn1f8uSsaRlv7rXX_09mPME8V3y7dIDVAKJ0upvJvuyjnsNuAxXVAKvXjNdesKE_GMc3P5ZH6tOBb78a3uLyTOVf-itdR0f2Y7932QPnWbOM1d45mYARUK8Q28IHlKnyhntkA9YP8HQfvFdyMnAKhzPiybSU3Hg1U6wOh6qeYOqN4IIUedzZz__HFZZLpfPJHUacEXfgOWlPO3ZryMxN9v13pDG223oHl-9zbCOdtNsU3igOWlDM4094MECfpYWWem9cuEnbADjsyqVaq0l3CoL8MLUvDKpEjgI7ezopX0UFOlTWXjDxK-EmWeHOJlUAOjRJKUtmJBhiqtjY4quWsTO5xRzX-_fPyFw2Cql2T2_03FDNgZY6u8GpvmBR3f9E1jXqzNI36vbIdtBa6l0tksOPBnLeG070boMdViKMdUxAjzCW1EcUvaXo_vgOZ-ZU8_loOvGBOYmzE6myesQCMDaHXrSJROoR-G5lk5OO-hED6KWUptkqKI5vAuAHGuojq0_1d2YT4X4e8._jpZ8zc1XWIEFVmu.TKbdl02R_2q6-QwtW4cnUiNDoXhFX_fkTDxrhxofM8BhLTMhMk1cx3jvSPJADftBd5NgHghOouZePw_NwapFpNUwgFq__QvPVKcw6QQwU1IKcuh-ShfSJRtr9oVC93zQprZSvgLJsf5K-46sbjnEBc6dzCsL07r3M9fbg4XwaJyRW7iriLTXFbFEd-CbsqlGgZupHGUbn0W_h5PVYTuwAp4I7wyp_k2xF0i9MQRcLk04fm--zdwYo7-FfM3yfsz129OXzpH7tp6c_dl-5D53_cleLFLAIn1BNnDwVFfKIPkjbjz8_NzGoXWWESW8DP00Z2Of4qVgdhtBWunduriM7NyDWaiDWgePt3qX0A3nvSp6bIp9sXdZYiuGVM3z7-iMb-oJPsj1Abx5MuRHpbvovNLHY89QnV8Qf43TCUOGxpgiNcULd4QxeLn2NmXcmbxlFVxhGHxq44XHF0A14dEiWSYp4001T7lun-yv3DPZuiGiO-L4iKHZT-gnHAzjaDIyXVo5JsL1qWGVi59DJneQrnyjodZs7ESCUIbOASJ5SJ9QtSOu-uyvKVdyK6Tfw9-cGNXAzDBAOBmHcnxMOtWcZ6AscDJhpI_2quoktpTD9GkEM0gItKZ5W3r99i8t_RoZCakBdBY6D5gwVg4yFsJyb1YvqsYsH1X8MQBPdrVBTc4DUT0M0ucpfl5bV3nlMxxEffCyk-jbNNXid9_kOjq4Xv3-pHO4qJUQpJvRYIvGqyC0Ep1swo3-gbsUIjtEfyLlf2JkcDIM5WkV_iSvEbjch9lceTMKzjQVZgMnDWPvTtEvAZCXUxbRu9wE9fuX9F2W-yJ_DyB0o871IOhdDi0VyQcipQ2wkvuZecu9uqLFGtVk5NaPxYq0uOyaDQ3QzDwucAMwalaXPua9qjhLjM6TCePgn_ncVdN5jckMXo--RRAX3o4G1Hm8_xcJ6Amcvl8vsb7hUTdXY6um6CT-WDHbi-FQgMyyn-vlC64NJdngvT3uWvcKETS8UoKhp78nFDy20qWXIqSzxwi7rf60OL7vPZ_6McVfXORTbMjxvGRTT5skgkY58B5VPvB1c6vN12tKN3E3lqbJCpzass0rSzbfBxdRDg-PIV-Nuv0S-ch9aUxA5h6cMrYBZMQuiV-RO3EoqfQSU0JNGJuGir8mQAKuI5pJwROKrn1cCAaTSrcueobXz_ppJgZdxzjh_dUzZhfUrrE7DqJgPqHbuEPju7ViB39iPLsiniDz3W1iOhQKSbFDNzLmG_yzjKv1jF90onqIyo_mLN3kVlxHyvgP4MA8405OJCR_Cqmob0djhkiRsJCfNWUuVmmq0q0YPTfFIAn_R9A9Zdlwd8Ybg88_RKegLMwySgvfWT27w2OwGMQX6kCrPxV5pWS57lgmPiflq-R1H1uHXvBDoXySx3Uzv1J2ElzvtQGVufZFBznnirsQI87cwxSz76gWiVelf4GNJzRme3O1XRPhmlMlTBWCHOASRxTo9mM964oHc5g3cIRWrzNFppTV_FkJQ6cwPFYYjFdSA3Hh1w8_RxCxyXncsunAZoniCgV6KEBN7A5KybKMu424JQqWqdlKQqHBW7XLdqMnMH-ryzie22fGmIn4RrT5ha6ZI43rvLREt_4dYJJpmh4yw1f7Bh-8mIuKd1ha3lERWP0qZhSR6sSsCHob_UTe4JW_KwVT0om4FAgMzbLoKoZf1v01QHHn0ISSH9cvtgwv8TObcleMkEYrDJ_MxsSxOKm-B7VoKFDEhtns0ybZA_QYEK40voAzhrGO4CPjsOR7tWKIUFk3veNJRxmixBeGVP7Up7KAvXk7wAhRg060MzZ0Gf4kaWi6IS-H_hWSPYbb0NO0IQRcGYFXALt58p0hO61HpUqG5gnQGiceiMnj1DVKIVAbtnUhB_rGcrePPCKT_TQIeCyO4FRjtHw73iYePZgacVEJDGOqthPlVWJpKF9IWeUu5Ngqc3j6L75bQ4uuvUGVHAORbH3bzXoxxqx4hjU2kI0KvQwGs0VC6rCCgC2GCqJmn3-W0jxir9Mw3VBMaBOOpslv-FSMLriL4UX1solBR3pZ7bCm1vGCUooaj9tG0Pp4n6dwqGz54hkJ5vgYX5xEKZMYYJxhhKomRFNzvhJtli9qe4lNLUsMHEnwcs-BX1tMi7JSOxmPm5BNT_A7qYeRj4dJh4cR926geYdQpcXHhYC9qyNXuqsLG5Qf88rPqMeQerwBmxcwGbTUh2eUpSu4dZZzWuCUiG92Fb55UBtElxZ0mDsQ6SPso6g44oaBNaBbOJ1DnigSE6n1X-yz2HyRjYKHLCpbSHz2xDpQaHSUMVuHphOlS69Wn0Mwb_HljnQU0S34HJya1-zivBIDepkmt3_9EhLy3La872n3H1IEzkaNX7cjCr77imU2lQ32G1iwbFAo4FvJfkJhYwP2xLh1Q38GeE_2vsiQlu1iFr3Fs_Wxv-hYW6rnAz1B_1MSOI0slWMQywIhqZ7dbyyWv_S-oxecVneZ4LlSW-hxCYJGtrsGJtnEaRHVYZJ-N-MjwBm9nJU4P8mY9Nz9MPbWbovb8gJ5DLXFppZjReRk2A2zHTGKzav6Q0DYKI0NGmSDHJW6UbSjVzBBJe2r85NS4u5HGS_wyEhXXnMtJZdn6VBQj9AEY4Jrt2xZzCRoqWlUI46uMObvWq5qvkKCPcSLKyrHEIigbR3JmW3zzDNvc39RmiC6cbJ0Ypb-G0D4CNwdV2bemLzs29NIWms75cqMHxlkyKOqEX5UsYlGBhra_kM.vykYzq6TQ8ApQdyREGo6-g

var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
jwtSettings.RegisterMapper(new JwtPayloadConverter.JsonMapperJwt());

var decodedJwt = Jose.JWT.Decode(paylaodRetornoStone2, rsa, Jose.JweAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_256, Jose.JweEncryption.A256GCM, jwtSettings);
```

when i try do decrypt the payload, i'm getting this error: **specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm**.

the specific part of code that is throwing this exception is the:

```
  byte[] cek = keyManagement.Unwrap(encryptedCek, key, jweAlgorithm.KeySize, header);
```

the implementation of RsaOaep256KeyManagement is doing this:

```
  return Ensure.Type<RSA>(key, "RsaKeyManagement algorithm expects key to be of RSA type.").Decrypt(encryptedCek, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
```

it seens that paddind mode is right, anyone have an idea to how fix this error?

Comment: You use the RSA-OAEP-256 algorithm to encrypt the content encryption key to the recipient to generate the JWE encryption key, and then use the AES-256-GCM algorithm to encrypt the plaintext key to generate the JWE ciphertext, and then you want to proceed The decryption of the ciphertext?